# Can I skip a test (or mark it as inconclusive) in pytest while it is running?

Tags: python, pytest

I am aware of `pytest`'s decorators to mark tests as to be skipped (conditionally). However, all those are evaluated before the test starts.

I have a couple of tests that require a user interaction (those are not run on [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) obviously), and if that interaction is not provided, I would like to mark these tests as, well, anything but "pass" or "fail". "Skipped" would be fine, as would be "inconclusive" or "canceled" or whatever.

Is that possible?

Comment: Obviously not enough information, but it looks like these are poorly designed tests if user interaction is required and is better to refactor them, Apart from that, I would say you should just mark them skip them and run them manually/separately

Comment: @buran what is bad about converting manual tests into semi-automated tests if fully-automated is not possible (e.g., because a button on an external device has to be pressed to generate data)? Would you still say "these are poorly designed tests"?

Comment: you can mock the external hardware, provide reliable/predictable input and test accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can call `pytest.skip()` from inside a test as well.

```py
try:
    ...
except some.TimeoutException:
    pytest.skip("Timeout waiting for user interaction")
```

works fine.